# deleting ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, partitioning, windows-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to remove Ubuntu and put Windows back on?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on)

i have ubuntu 12.10 with windows 7 installed on the same hard drive. ubuntu and windows are both installed on different partitions. I would like to remove ubuntu but I don't know which partition it is installed on to remove it. is there a partition manager in ubuntu to tell me which one it is on. because I want to keep my windows 7 but remove ubuntu.
Thanks,

Comment: In Windows it is the one NOT formatted as NTFS but is shown as unknown ;) Gparted can tell you this or even `fdisk` but you will see them shown as `sdb1` and windows does not show them as that. sda1 is the 1st (a) disc, 1st partition (1), sdb2 is the 2nd disc 2nd partition.

Answer (score 0):

Your hard drive should be /dev/sda. If it is not, change to the hard drive number.
type `sudo fdisk /dev/sda`
Then type "p" to print table. Look for linux partition id (83) and swap. It will have a nuber after it, like sda6. To avoid any changes to your partition, make sure to tyoe "q" to exit. type "n" to show all option. It is self explanatory, but dangerous if you mess up.The NTFS is the windows partition.